# How to store NUMERIC value as given in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, types, database-migration

In Oracle when you have a NUMBER data type and do not specify precision and scale like `NUMBER(18,2)` for example and use it like this `NUMBER` instead it will store the value as given.

[From the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313)

> If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given

Now I want to know if there is a way to let NUMERIC data type in SQL Server do the same. I have to use NUMERIC and not DECIMAL or other data types and I am not allowed to specify the precision or scale since I have no possibility to test if the data that will be used will cause errors because I have no access to the data. I just know that the data did not cause any trouble with our Oracle database which uses only NUMBER datatype without any specifications.

Comment: SQL Server has no direct counterpart to Oracle's `NUMBER`. Also, in SQL Server `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are synonyms, so your demand that "you have use `NUMERIC` and not `DECIMAL`" is not coherent -- that's not a real choice. Typically, just because the column is `NUMBER` does not mean it will literally store everything a `NUMBER` is capable of storing -- closer investigation should reveal the most appropriate T-SQL type(s). If you have no access to the data, then the safest type to use is actually a string type -- but only so you can inspect and convert the values later.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: and the default if one uses just `DECIMAL` is `DECIMAL(18,0)` - so no digits after the decimal point .....

Comment: @marc_s: if the `NUMBER` isn't used to store fractional values (which can often be deduced from context) that wouldn't even be such a bad default for conversion purposes (larger values are not probable, but will trigger an overflow if they occur anyway). The problem being, of course, that if you get it wrong and the column was storing fractional values anyway, SQL Server will silently round them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, numeric needs a precision and scale and has defaults if none are set. Simple like that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Quote:

> decimal[ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )] Fixed precision and scale
>   numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38
>   +1 through 10^38 - 1. The ISO synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.

Like often, documentation is your friend.